# Itens do listview perdendo cor quando usa a barra de rolagem

Tags: android, listview

Estou utilizando baseAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int posicao, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertview;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_lista, parent, false);
        holder.itemNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNome);
        holder.itemEndereco = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.itemEndereco);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    Telefone item = getItem(posicao);
    holder.itemNome.setText(item.getNome());
    holder.itemEndereco.setText(item.getTelefone());
    return view;
}
```

> Mas os itens ficam "bugados":
>
> 1. Quando seleciono um item fica com cor de fundo vermelha, depois realizo uma rolagem e a cor desaparece voltando para o original, pois estou usando viewHolder e a view é "reciclada ou reutilizada";
> 2. Tem itens que ficam com cor de fundo vermelha sem ser o item selecionado.

Comment: Você quer trocar a cor sempre que clicar? É isso?

Comment: Sim... eu já consegui isso, mas tem mais problemas acima descrito são 3 problemas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito penar consegui, vlw pela ajuda @Wakim e @Cícero Moura:

```
@Override
public View getView(int posicao, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertview;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_lista, parent, false);
        holder.itemNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNome);
        holder.itemEndereco = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.itemEndereco);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if (listener.getPosicao() == posicao
            && listener.statusSelecao()) {
        holder.itemNome.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        holder.itemEndereco.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
        else {
            holder.itemNome.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(65, 105, 225));
            holder.itemEndereco.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(65, 105, 225));
    }

    Telefone item = getItem(posicao);
    holder.itemNome.setText(item.getNome());
    holder.itemEndereco.setText(item.getTelefone());
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, é o seguinte:

Toda vez que você rola um ListView, os itens que "somem" para cima ou para baixo são destruídos.

Então, quando são recriados novamente, voltam ao estado original, sem a sua customização.

O que você pode fazer é criar um adapter e setar esse estado, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
  private final Context context;
  private final Item[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, Item[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.your_row_layout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false);

     TextView itemNome= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemNome);
     TextView itemEndereco= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemEndereco);
     CheckBox check = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.check);


     Item item = getItem(position);

     itemNome.setText(item.getNome());
     itemEndereco.setText(item.getEndereco());

     if(check.isChecked()){

      rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
else{

     rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

}

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

O código acima é só um exemplo.

Mas espero que o que realmente tenha entendido é que os itens são destrídos ao rolar e reconstruídos quando são visualizados, voltando ao estado original.

Sobre o erro que dá quando rola até mais embaixo, no adapter, você poderá colocar um breackpoint e debugar.

Vi que está utilizando o padrão ViewHolder, então atente-se apenas para esse fato, da reciclagem.

Comment: postei o print.. e não tem como fazer as alteracões no adapter usando baseAdapter?

Comment: esse erro etá justamente quando uso listView.getChildAt(posicao).findViewById(R.id.itemNome).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); o erro está na posição..

Comment: já arrumei o 2ª e 3ª erros.. só falta o primeiro... com relação a rolagem... quando eu seleciono um item e depois rolo a cor dele desaparece.

Comment: @PedroRangel, você precisa guardar dentro do Adapter quais elementos estão selecionados. Para não depender de tela apenas. O `check.isChecked` tem que usar alguma informação extra, no caso um `Set` ou `SparseArray`.

Comment: @Wakim eu procurei bastante e havia encontrado esse linha de código android:scrollingCache="false" para adicionar mas mesmo assim não funciona..

Comment: @PedroRangel, não é isso não. Você não pode apenas fazer as marcações nas `Views`. Porque ao dar scroll elas são reconstruídas e esse estado se perde. Você precisa gerenciar quem está marcado dentro do seu `Adapter` e não usar o `isChecked` do `Checkbox` e sim do estado do `Adapter`.

Comment: @Wakim blz... mas não to utilizando checkbox de qualquer maneira, acho que você ta olhando o código da resposta^^..

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o setCacheColorHint

Ex:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hinario_left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#669966"));
```